# Facebook Graph API gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-graph-api, rubygems

I wanted to use the Facebook graph API in my rails app.

What is the recommended gem to work with the FB graph APIs?

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

This is a well written FB graph support for Ruby - https://github.com/nov/fb_graph

Comment: I'd like to note that I'm personally in favor of koala nowadays.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the Koala gem from https://github.com/arsduo/koala

Answer (score 3):

You can query the Graph API directly. The responses will be in JSON which you can then parse as needed. See the [Facebook Documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) for more details on the specific functions you can call and sample JSON responses.

I don't code in Ruby, but this seems like a great start on understanding [Ruby on Rails and JSON](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/04/inside-ruby-on-rails-serializing-ruby-objects-with-json/).