# How use Facebook APIs after authenticating with Devise/Omniauth?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, omniauth

I'm using Devise + the `omniauth-facebook` gem to log in to my Rails 3 app using Facebook (see [Rails 3 using Devise: How to allow someone to log in using their Facebook account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3580557/rails-3-using-devise-how-to-allow-someone-to-log-in-using-their-facebook-accoun)).

But how can I work with the Graph/OpenGraph API once authenticated? Use another gem such as Koala?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a gem, or just treat it "RESTFully". Check out some useful docs from [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/facebook-ruby#the_facebook_graph_api).

There's a similar question to yours too: [Facebook Graph API gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5875348/facebook-graph-api-gem)