# External website interaction with facebook page, where and how to start?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a basic question regarding facebook pages and implementing them on an external website.
I have a facebook page with several 1000 posts. Each post contains an image.

Now I want to implement some sort of collection on an external website where I list all those posts and of course showing the like/share/comment feature of each post, so the user can interact with each post on my website (if he is logged in to Facebook).

Additionally, I like to add more attributes to the posts such as "title" or "description" or a "tag" which should be connected to each post and be hosted on my site. In an ideal model, I would tell my application the page-post-ID of a post and add several more attributes to it. The app would then visit my facebook page, posts the post-ID via the FB API and loads it via GET on my website. I know that this would mean some work, adding each post ID into the database and having a few hundreds of posts already.

I have not seen this yet in the facebook API but maybe it is possible quite easily.

I am using rails to implement this project. So if you have any tipps or feedback how and where I can get started with this idea, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with using [Facebook Graph API gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5875348/facebook-graph-api-gem), use OAuth to authorize users. Then use the 'feed' field of the current user, which contains feed posts.

Here are [Docs and examples for posting messages](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/publishing/). Use your page ID instead of PROFILE_ID to post to a page.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I use OAuth in other apps as well but is it really necessary here to authorize a user if in fact the fanpage itself is being loaded? I have seen this in some examples - I don't want any user to log in via my page. Rather see the posts and if he is logged into facebook or likes the page already, be able to like/share/comment each post.
Also I am not interested in the users feed posts, only in the ones from my page and only those I like to (if possible via feed-post-ID)

Comment: I thought you need to authorize users on an external website. If you load a FB page, you've already got and access_token for authorized users. If there is an access_token parameter, you can query /me to find out more about the user. As for the page's feed, I believe you should use the PAGE_ID/feed connection as described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#feed . And it should work without access_token.

Comment: Cool. Also found this docu: https://github.com/nov/fb_graph/wiki/Page-Management
It says "You need the page’s access token" - tried to find that but no success so far.